# AWK script. Looking for an optimized example

Tags: sed, awk

I've borrowed and written the following code to output the disconnect time. All works well but I'm curious as to how I could tighten/ shorten the code. If anyone feels like having some fun then I'd love to see what can be done. Be a learning lesson for me.

Cheers in advance.

Input:

```
ftp> !:--- FTP commands below here ---
ftp> lcd C:\Utilities\Performance_Testing\
\Utilities\Performance_Testing\: File not found 
Verbose mode On .
ftp> verbose
binary
200 Switching to Binary mode.
ftp> put "test_file_5M.bin"
200 PORT command successful.
150 Ok to send data.
226 File receive OK.
ftp: 5242880 bytes sent in Seconds Kbytes/sec.
ftp> 44.81117.00disconnect
221 Goodbye.
ftp> bye
```

Code:

```
#Obtain UT external put value.
ut1intput=$(awk '
  NR==70 {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
      if($i=="ftp>") {
        sub(/disconnect/, "", $(i+1));
        print $(i+1)
      }
    }
  }' filename.txt)

utintputvalue=`echo $ut1intput | awk -F. '{print $2"."$3}'| sed  's/^..//'`
```

Output:

```
UT external put value is 1220.98
```

Comment: Apologies. Didn't know about Code Review. Will repost there.

Comment: How are you getting that output from the posted input? Why are you looking for line 70 in a file that has 15 lines? Where did the words `UT external put value is` come from? Where did the value `1220.98` come from? If you want to see a script to do a job, at a minimum post same input and the output you need to get from that input.

Comment: I snipped the example input from a large file. Line 70 refers to the physical location of "ftp> 44.81117.00disconnect". Sorry, I inadvertently c/p the wrong return. Should read 117.00.

Comment: question on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46074/3219)

Comment: @ten1267 Edit your question to show actual sample input and expected out that we can work with.

Answer (score 0):

Given your posted sample input and the desired output you said you want in your comment:

```
$ sed -n 's/^.*\(......\)disconnect/UT external put value is \1/p' file
UT external put value is 117.00
```